# Round off in C++ on basis of Number length

Tags: c++, boost

in c++, I need to roundoff number on basis of lenght
Total Length of Number should be 18 only including decimal and after decimal only 5 digit

Example 1: if a = 12345678910.12345467 then result should be 12345678910.12345

Example 2: if a=9876543123345667.23445 then result should be 9876543123345667.2

Comment: Is your number stored in a string? I guess so because `double` only has 16 significant digits. Or are you using a numeric type defined in boost?

Comment: Currently I am using string... Please suggest what to do

Comment: The strings are too long to fit into any of the standard numeric types. Therefore you need to use some multi-precision library (boost has some types that might be useful but I can't help with the details here) or you need to implement the rounding algorithm youself. In the latter case, you could start with the last character, check if it is a digit >=5, if yes, increment the previous character that is a digit and so on, until nothing is left to round. Be sure to treat special cases like 999.9999999999999999999 correctly.